find-file backslash causes searching
Using emacs on Windows. When I use find-file, when I have ido-mode set to t, if I type in a new path, e.g. w:\, then I get a message that says searching for 'w:\'... and a long pause followed by no match.
When I type in w:/ it starts a new path rooted at w:\. How do I get find-file to process backslash like it processes forward slash?

Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with emacs -Q (no init file)? I don't, in any Emacs release.

If you do, then please post a reproducible step-by-step recipe starting from emacs -Q, saying what you see at each step and what you expected to see instead.

If you don't, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.



So I have (require 'ido) and (ido-mode t) in my .emacs and it is ido-mode that is causing the issue.

It isn't really a fix for the issue.
